# Unable to login to Azure Databse using "Azure Active Directory - Integrated" or x86 ODBC connections

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

I’m not able to connect to my Azure database using “Azure Active Directory – Integrated” when using SSMS 17 or x86 ODBC connections, but I’m able to connect with SSMS 19 and x64 ODBC connections.
I know this has been discussed extensively before, my issue is similar to this posting:
[Unable to load adalsql.dll error when calling `Invoke-sqlcmd`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45578395/unable-to-load-adalsql-dll-error-when-calling-invoke-sqlcmd/)
In my case the x86 applications are not working and the x64 are fine. All of this seem to have started after installing SSMS 19, I have:

Both x86 and x64 ADAL files, I have also tried with each one without the other on my system:
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\AdalSQL.dll
C:\Windows\System32\AdalSQL.dll

…and their Registry entries is there:
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSADALSQL]\TargetDir  = C:\WINDOWS\system32\adalsql.dll

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\MSADALSQL]\TargetDir =
C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\adalsql.dll

When I use SSMS 17 I get this message:
[image: SSMS Q7 Error]

I have removed both SSMS 18 and 19 and started from scratch but that did not help. I have followed the recommendations on the posting above with no luck. It seems that I have everything I need, but I can’t pinpoint what the issue is or what is that I’m missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read below.

> If any of your applications use the Azure Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL) for authentication and authorization functionality, it's time to migrate them to the Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL).
>
> All Microsoft support and development for ADAL, including security fixes, ends in December, 2022.

For more information, please read [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-entra-azure-ad-blog/have-you-updated-your-applications-to-use-the-microsoft/ba-p/1144698?wt.mc_id=DP-MVP-4015656).

As you can read [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-entra-azure-ad-blog/have-you-updated-your-applications-to-use-the-microsoft/ba-p/1144698?wt.mc_id=DP-MVP-4015656) Microsoft intended to end support back in June 2022, but it extended support 6 months more. Have you considered to quickly [migrating to MSAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-migration?wt.mc_id=DP-MVP-4015656).